# Configure OSGi dependency injection at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, osgi

OSGi declarative services seem to require an XML descriptor referenced in the bundle's Service-Component manifest header, which has to be added to the bundle at compile time. Spring DM seems to do the same.

How do you get dependency injection to happen after the module is compiled, ie. plug classes together using some sort of configuration file in the filesystem that's parsed at bundle activation time?

Comment: In Equinox you can add new plug-ins at runtime using the "install" command at the OSGi console. To access the OSGi console from outside configure it to be reachable over telnet as shown [here][1]. 

What's your exact use case?

  [1]: http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html#osgiintro_telnet

Comment: My use case is for instance selecting which JDBC driver to use. But I think the answer is that you can't really select the implementation class to use the way you can in Spring, all you can do is select an interface, and you control which implementation class gets used by controlling which bundles providing that interface are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSGi, you have *µservices*, these are objects that *components* register with a *service registry*. The XML in Declarative Services (DS) describes the service(s) a component class wants to register and it declares the dependencies, the services required by this component class.

When the bundle that holds the component class gets activated, DS is notified and reads the XML descriptor to find out about the dependencies. When all the mandatory dependencies are met, it instantiates the component class and injects the required services using Java reflection. The services are plain java objects implementing a service interface. Once the injection has taken place it (optionally) calls the activate method on the component and then registers the component as a service.

If the dependencies (services) change then the component is modified or it is shutdown. This can be repeated until the bundle is stopped.

So for a general answer, a injector can read a configuration file, instantiate mentioned classes, and wire them together from this description. OSGi is quite unique since it not only allows the creation of the wiring but can also unwire components.

Now your use case. Only in the most extreme cases should you select the JDBC implementation. The whole idea of OSGi is that the deployer picks a JDBC driver that you should use. So as you indicated yourself, you should use whatever is in the registry. This model allows the deployer more flexibility in selecting a JDBC driver.

However, sometimes you really need this unique feature of vendor X's JDBC driver. In such a case, the best solution is to use the implementation class in your code, this will allow tools to find out that you have this implementation dependency.